# String manipulate using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string lets say  `C1 AND C2 OR C3 (~!@#$%) AND C4 OR C5` 
and say my input is `C3` 
then i want to delete the junk/data between `C3` and next operator `AND|OR` using regex.

so for the above string i want output as `C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4 OR C5`

Comment: Is the junk data always enclosed in parentheses? Also, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: `No` .. it can be anything for ex `C1 AND C2 OR C3 ~!@#$% ()()()() ### AND C4 OR C5`

Comment: also it need to be provided the input(C1/C2/C3....) as input can be C2 .. which dont have any junk .. then i am not supposed to delete junk after C3

Comment: Are your variables always of the form `Cn` (where n is a number)? Give us specifics about your data so that we don't have to make assumptions. What about the following `C1 AND C2 OR C2 ANDC1ANDC2$$#@@ORC3 AND C4`. Can this happen? Should that garbage in the center be removed?

Comment: Yes .. always of the form `Cn` also operators are always going to be only `AND|OR` .. also there cant be multiple C2 or C1 .. or any Cn in string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = 'C1 AND C2 OR C3 (~!@#$%) AND C4 OR C5'
var input = 'C3'
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp("(" + input + " ).*?(AND|OR)"), "$1$2"))
```

Comment: This is extremely specific to the input string and will not work in all cases.

Comment: You would have to replace C3 with whatever your input is.

Answer (score 0):

```
function purgeJunk(variable, expression) {
    return expression.replace(purgeJunk.regexp, function(match, digits, operator) {
        if (digits != variable) return match;
        return "C" + digits + " " + operator;
    });
};

function purgeAllJunk(expression) {
    return expression.replace(purgeJunk.regexp, function(match, digits, operator) {
        return "C" + digits + " " + operator;
    });
};

purgeJunk.regexp = /C(\d+) .*?(AND|OR)/g;

// delete junk after C2
purgeJunk(2, "C1 AND C2 OR C3 (~!@#$%) AND C4 OR C5") 
    == "C1 AND C2 OR C3 (~!@#$%) AND C4 OR C5"

// delete junk after C3
purgeJunk(3, "C1 AND C2 OR C3 (~!@#$%) AND C4 OR C5") 
    == "C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4 OR C5"

// delete all junk
purgeAllJunk("C1 # AND C2 OR C3 ~!@#$% ()()()() ### AND C4 more garbage OR C5")
    == "C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4 OR C5"
```